# Integration with Facebook Initial ViewController has a UITabBarController instead of UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk, ios6

The title pretty much says it all. I'm trying to create an interface where after connecting with Facebook, the window loads up my `HomeViewController` (my initially selected `UITabBarItem`). Although, I do not want the `UINavigationBar` that comes through as I have set the `HomeViewController` as the `LoginViewController`'s root view. I have different navigation bar items for each view, so defaulting to that one won't work. I have this code now.

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.mainViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.mainViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good nights sleep, I was able to figure it out. Hopefully, this can help others out there!

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    // Initialize view controllers
    HomeViewController *homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    ConnectViewController *connectViewController = [[ConnectViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConnectViewController" bundle:nil];
    PartyControlViewController *partyControlViewController = [[PartyControlViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PartyControlViewController" bundle:nil];
    MeViewController *meViewController = [[MeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MeViewController" bundle:nil];
    MoreViewController *moreViewController = [[MoreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MoreViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:homeViewController, connectViewController, partyControlViewController, meViewController, moreViewController, nil]];

    // Customize Tab Bar
    UITabBarItem *homeTab = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" image:nil tag:0];
    UITabBarItem *connectTab = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connect" image:nil tag:1];
    UITabBarItem *partyControlTab = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Party Control" image:nil tag:2];
    UITabBarItem *meTab = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Me" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"person.png"] tag:3];
    UITabBarItem *moreTab = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemMore tag:4];

    [homeViewController setTabBarItem:homeTab];
    [connectViewController setTabBarItem:connectTab];
    [partyControlViewController setTabBarItem:partyControlTab];
    [meViewController setTabBarItem:meTab];
    [moreViewController setTabBarItem:moreTab];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom tabbar Class add it in appDelegate

appDelegate.m

```
self.tabBarVC = [[[TabBarVC alloc] init] autorelease];
self.navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.tabBarVC]autorelease]; 
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
```

TabBarVC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TabBarVC : UITabBarController


@end
```

TabBarVC.m

```
#import "TabBarVC.h" 
#import "ViewController1.h" 
#import "ViewController2.h"


@implementation TabBarVC


 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; 

    UIViewController *vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController1" bundle:nil];


    UIViewController *vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];

    [self setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1,vc2, nil]];  


}

@end
```

Comment: This doesn't work for a few reasons. Firstly, the `UINavigationBar` is carried into the `HomeViewController`. Secondly, the method you used in the app delegate is a two-stage (deprecated) method.

Comment: try to fix error, It must work for you. or let me send you a sample project later

Comment: The error is one I'm familiar with. It means that in the app delegate, you're trying to set a root view controller of a navigationController's root view controller. iPhone 6.0 does not allow this "two-stage" process, and requires it to be one step. My original question asks how to do this while including a `UITabBarController`, and excluding the `UINavigationBar`, which is still inclusive within the sample code you provided.